# How to remove `_id` field from the query result of mongoDB?

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, laravel

I am using `laravel-mongodb`(https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) to manipulate mongodb data.

I want to transfer data into mysql that queried from mongodb,there is a demo function to do this:

TestController.php

```
public function queryAndInsertMysql()
{
    $articles = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('articles')->get()->toArray();

    DB::connection('mysql')->table('articles')->insert($articles);

    dd('ok');
}
```

There is an error when running this function:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `articles` (`_id`, `content`, `title`) values (59ad186437dd1f1968004334, hello..., hello), (59ad186437dd1f1968004335, foo..., foo), (59ad186437dd1f1968004336, bar..., bar))
```

The error occurs because there is an `_id` field in mongodb collection,
and there is no `_id` field in mysql table,
so I need to remove `_id` field before insert them into mysql.

I try to do this with `array_shift()` but it doesn't work:

```
public function removeId()
{
    $articles = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('articles')->get()->toArray();

    foreach ($articles as $article) {
        array_shift($article);
    }


    dd($articles);
}
```

The `_id` fields still exist:

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use projection to filter the `_id` out:

```
public function queryAndInsertMysql()
{
    $articles = DB::connection('mongodb')
        ->collection('articles')
        ->project(['_id' => 0])
        ->get()
        ->toArray();

    DB::connection('mysql')->table('articles')->insert($articles);

    dd('ok');
}
```

Please note that mongodb is shemaless, unless you enforce it with [document validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document-validation/), so it would be advisable to whitelist all the fields you expect to insert into SQL in the `project` argument:

```
public function queryAndInsertMysql()
{
    $articles = DB::connection('mongodb')
        ->collection('articles')
        ->project(['_id' => 0, 'content' => 1, 'title' => 1])
        ->get()
        ->toArray();

    DB::connection('mysql')->table('articles')->insert($articles);

    dd('ok');
}
```

It will guarantee that even if you accidentally have a document with any other field, it will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

That is a nested array so you will need to use the extended [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop,

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    /** Shift here... **/
}
```

**Example**

```
<?php
$a = [
    0 => [
        '_id' => 'sdgsdg'    
    ]
];

$y = '';

foreach ($a as $key => $val) {
    $y =  array_shift($a[$key]);  
}

var_dump($y); /** ---> string(6) "sdgsdg" **/
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel Collections map function can help you with this:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-map

remove the _id field and the you can insert them into your MySQL DB