# Getting/Select data in Laravel without object ID using MongoDB

Tags: laravel, mongodb, query-builder

This is my controller class :

```
public function validation(Request $request)
    {
        $email= $request->input('email');
        $password= $request->input('password');

        if (DB::table('customer')
            ->where('email','=',$email)
            ->where('password','=',$password)
            ->exists())
        {
            $name=DB::table('customer')
            ->select('first_name')
            ->where('email','=',$email)
            ->get();

            echo $name;
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Invalid Email or Password';
        }
      }
```

Model :

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table='customer';

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

And here's the result :

> ```
> [{"_id":{"$oid":"64d20430d721b3ea940180e2"},"first_name":"John"}]
> ```

How to show only first_name without _id ?
Should I change my Model ? or What ???
Thanks Before...

Comment: Can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46035188/how-to-remove-id-field-from-the-query-result-of-mongodb

Answer (score -1):

The result you are getting is a JSON array with an object containing _id and first_name. If you want to display only the first_name value without the _id, you can access it using array indexing.

Here's how you can modify your controller code to achieve that:

```
public function validation(Request $request)
{
$email = $request->input('email');
$password = $request->input('password');

if (DB::table('customer')
    ->where('email', '=', $email)
    ->where('password', '=', $password)
    ->exists())
{
    $customer = DB::table('customer')
        ->select('first_name')
        ->where('email', '=', $email)
        ->first(); // Use first() to get a single row as an object

    echo $customer->first_name;
}
else
{
    echo 'Invalid Email or Password';
}
}
```

By using the first() method instead of get(), you'll get a single row as an object, and you can directly access the first_name property of that object without dealing with _id. This should give you the desired output of only the first_name.